# Reactive operator that works like bufferWhen but only for the latest variable

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, rxjs, reactive

I searched through the various operators on the reactive website. I am unable to figure out how set a chain of rx operators so that it stores the most recent observable until another observable allows it be released.

For example:

```
Source0: 0 . . 1 . . . 2 . 3
Source1: F F F F T F F F T T
Result:  . . . . 1 . . . 2 3
```

And code like

```
const result = (action$, store) =>
   action$.ofType('SOME_TYPE').mostRecent(_ => store.getState().REDUCER.saving);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `combineLatest` first then use `filter`, finally `map` may be used to get your desired data:

```
source0.combineLatest(source1).filter(([s0, s1])=>s1).map(([s0,s1])=>s0);
```

Comment: This is so close. The only issue I realized was that Source1 is not an observable. Its a value from the redux's store. I prefer if it calls the redux's store.getState whenever it reaches the source1 spot. How would I incorporate that?

Comment: If source1 is not an Observable, it may be converted to an Observable, for example: Observable.of(source1) or new Subject().next(source1)